# Ionic Framework Page Transition

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Does anyone successfully add a page transition on nested views in angularjs/ionicframework

This is my code for my nested views. When I go to this page transition is not working

```
<ion-side-menus>
    <ion-nav-view name="left"></ion-nav-view>
    <ion-nav-view name="main"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-side-menus>
```

But if I put only this code

```
<ion-nav-view name="main"></ion-nav-view>
```

Page transition is working

I hope you can help me with this one. Thank you!

Comment: I really dont think you should have <ion-nav-views> inside a side menu

Comment: hi @JessPatton, can you recommend what tags should I use, I'm having a headache with this transition :(

Answer (score 0):

In you index.html you should have a single ion-nav-view (you can populate this ion nav view with multiple ion views) like so:

```
<div ng-app="ffApp" animation="slide-left-right" ng-controller="authRoute.controller">
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

Then you want to create states/child states to fill the view:

```
 $stateProvider
            .state('authenticate', {
                url: '/authenticate',
                templateUrl: 'templates/authentication.html'
            })
            .state('loginIos', {
                url: '/loginIos',
                templateUrl: 'templates/loginIos.html',
                controller: 'loginIos.controller',
            })
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                controller: 'home.controller',
            }).state('home.home1', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "home.html"
        }
      }
    })
```

Inside the template file you will have a ion-view with a side menu, if you want to populate the side menu as a child state you can create a child state inside the state provider and then place a ion-nav-view in side menu.

```
    <ion-view>
     <ion-side-menus>
  <!-- Center content -->
  <ion-side-menu-content ng-controller="ContentController">
```

```
  <!-- Left menu -->
  <ion-side-menu side="left">
  </ion-side-menu>

  <!-- Right menu -->
  <ion-side-menu side="right">
  </ion-side-menu>

  <ion-side-menu-content>
  <!-- Main content, usually <ion-nav-view> -->
  </ion-side-menu-content>
</ion-side-menus>

</ion-view>
```

then when you navigate to a child state such as home.home1 the template for home.home1 will fill the menucontent ion-nav-view which is included in the home state template.

See this example: http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/Bicmo/